# Pointer Assignment Issue in C code

Tags: pointers, networking, null, malloc, assign

```
int rtadd(IPaddr net, IPaddr mask, IPaddr gw, unsigned metric)
{
    struct route *prt, *srt, *prev;
    srt= malloc(sizeof(struct route));
    bool isdup;
    int hv = 0, i = 0;

    if (!Route.ri_valid)
        rtinit();

    prt = rtnew(net, mask, gw, metric);

    prt->rt_key = 0;
    for (i - 0; i < 32; ++i)
        prt->rt_key += (mask >> i) & 1;

    prev = NULL;
    hv = rthash(net);
    isdup = false;
    for (srt = rttable[hv]; srt; srt = srt->rt_next) //trouble point (issue with srt = rttable[hv])?
    {
        if (prt->rt_key > srt->rt_key) 
        {
            break;
        }
        if (srt->rt_net == prt->rt_net && srt->rt_mask == prt->rt_mask)
        {
            isdup = true;
            break;
        }
        prev = srt;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code I created a pointer `srt` and used a `malloc` command to initialize it. When I assign it to the array rttable which is declared as `struct route *rttable[RT_TSIZE];`, the `srt` pointer becomes NULL. What could be causing this?

The code which is being done for a project in my networking class is based off of  Douglas Comer's TCP/IP volume II book:

[https://www.amazon.com/Internetworking-TCP-Vol-Implementation-Internals/dp/0139738436](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0139738436)

Comment: `srt->rt_next` (which is assigned to `srt`) eventually becomes null, probably.

Comment: See I thought this as well, except after testing, the `srt` pointer becomes NULL after directly assigning it to `rttable[hv]`

Comment: Then `rttable[hv]` is null…

Comment: I don't think so as I initialize rttable here
`void rtinit(void)
{
 int i;

 for (i = 0; i < RT_TSIZE; ++i)
  rttable[i] = 0;
 Route.ri_bpool = malloc(sizeof(struct route));
 Route.ri_valid = true;
 Route.ri_default = NULL;
}`

Comment: You initialize `rttable`, but you don't initialize `rttable[hv]` (now you posted the code, in fact, you explicitly initialize all items to `0`).

Answer (score 1):

The malloc is now a memory leak since you are not actually using that allocated memory address.  In your for loop, you are re-assigning your src pointer to a different location in memory by pointing it to rttable[hv]. So, if you examined rttable[hv] you will most likely find it's value set to 0 or null.